# Dialog flow coversation in chatbot

Tags: api, dialogflow-es

How to response for confirmation input from the user in dialog flow api.ai

**Example :**

user says :I want a pizza

Chatresponse : Do you want cheese pizza?

User says: Yes..

In this case how to connect with previous questions and response.Can anyone suggest any idea.

Comment: What do you mean by "connect with previous questions"?

Answer (score 0):

Go to Dialogflow and create a new intent that looks like this:
[image]
Next create an follow up intent by going back to the intent screen (click on intents in the left panel) and click on `create followup intent` after hovering over your pizza intent:
[image]
Then click `yes`:
[image]
You will now have two intent: one that identifies the user's intent as "wanting pizza" and the other as a followup intent that will be triggered after the wanted pizza intent is matched that will capture if the user says "yes" or something similar.

Comment: Thank you so much @matthewayne